# Parse method for the custom class C#

Tags: c#

We all know this thing

```
bool.Parse(Session["foo"].ToString())
```

How do implement the same **PARSE** method for some custom class?

So if I have

```
class MyClass
{

}
```

It would be possible to do like

```
MyClass.Parse(Session["foo"])
```

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing? What's stopping your from simply writing the `Parse()` method?

Comment: well I need the syntax like this MyClass.Parse(Session["foo"]) and not like MyClass newclass = new MyClass();  newclass.Parse(Session["foo"])

Comment: And why don't you directly store `MyClass` in the `Session`?

Comment: Do you have an example for what kind of string you would like to be able to parse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is write a static method called Parse() for your class that takes the String and creates an Instance of MyClass with it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Parse(string input)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) throw new ArgumentException(input);

        var instance = new MyClass();

        // Parse the string and populate the MyClass instance

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution was the first one and it is a simple one.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this.

```
       public static MyCustomClass Parse(object o)
    {

        if (o == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            if (o is MyCustomClass)
                return (MyCustomClass)o;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Class MyCustomClass{
   public static MyCustomClass Parse(string str){
        if (str == "Whatever"){
             return new MyCustomClass();
        }
        else if (/*other conditions*/) {

        }
   }
}
```

Or, was there something else you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - you would need to write a moderate amount of code to implement it, but you can certainly do it manually if you must:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string First {get; private set;}
    public string Last {get; private set;}
    public MyClass(string first, string last) {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
    }
    public static bool Parse(string s, out MyClass res) {
        res = null;
        if (s == null) return false;
        var tokens = s.Split(new[] {';'});
        if (tokens.Length != 2) return false;
        res = new MyClass(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This version takes an output argument and returns `bool`; you can easily modify it to throw an exception and return `MyClass` "the factory method style".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class foo
{
 public static foo Parse(object obj)
 {
  return new foo(obj);
 }

 public foo(){}

 public foo(object obj)
 {
  //your code to parse from obj to foo..
 }
}
```

in your 'frame/outer' code:

```
var t = foo.Parse(someInstance);
```